# How do I paste a watermark on all slides of my PowerPoint Presentation with VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How do I add watermark (with shape slanted at 45 degrees-and grayed) to all slides of A PPT Presentation with VBA?

I created an input box to accept a string variable that would be watermarked on all slides of a PPT. I also tried creating a shape and feeding the variable inputted into it. I now have a challenge pasting this shape on the rest of the slides in the presentation but sending backward.

```
Option Explicit
Public thepresentn As Presentation
Public theslide As Slide
Public thetex As Shape
Sub ConfidentialProject()
    Set thepresentn = ActivePresentation
    Set theslide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(1)
    Set thetex = theslide.Shapes.Item(1)
    Dim WORD As String
    WORD = InputBox("Please Enter the text you want to appear as Watermark", _
        "Enter Text Here:")
    thetex.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = WORD
End Sub
```

I expect the watermark on the first slide to be replicated on all other slides.

Comment: Use the macro recorder to write code for you , then modify it. Record yourself adding a watermark and then add the loop, or select all the slides and add it all at once.

Comment: Thanks. But there seems to be no  record macro feature on the MS PPT Application. Could you help point me to it, if it does exist?

Comment: With all due respect, finding the macro recorder in PPT is a job for Google. You can do it. :)

Comment: @teylyn   
Create a macro in PowerPoint for Office 365 PowerPoint 2019 PowerPoint 2016 PowerPoint 2013     https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Create-a-macro-in-PowerPoint-5b07aff6-4dc9-462f-8fc9-66b4c5344e7e

Comment: I know you meant well but trust me I've looked for it. Even the link you dropped reads:                          " The macro recorder, used to automate frequent tasks, is not available in PowerPoint 2013 or newer versions. Instead, you can use Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) to create or edit macros. This includes editing those that were created in earlier versions of PowerPoint."

Comment: The subheader of the article says "PowerPoint for Office 365 PowerPoint 2019 PowerPoint 2016 PowerPoint 2013"

Comment: Thanks for the response. But myself, like many MSO users, use Powerpoint 2013, one of those listed by the article as not containing the feature.

Comment: "The subheader of the article says "PowerPoint for Office 365 PowerPoint 2019 PowerPoint 2016 PowerPoint 2013"  True. And then the first sentence says that the macro recorder's not available in PowerPoint.  Hasn't been since Office 2010 or before.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't quite get you. Do you agree with My assertion?

Comment: Sir, [Mr Rindsberg] A pleasure to have your comments here. just stumbled on your Website on PPT (VBA). I must say it has been very valuable. Any suggestions here would be nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

I have offered you TWO solutions. The first is using the slide master and the second is using the method you requested.

This will work by modifying your slide master. Not copy and paste. if you need copy and paste then, Please specify what to copy and paste (Text, Picture, etc...).

```
Option Explicit
Sub AddWaterMarkMaster()
    Dim intI As Integer
    Dim strWaterMark As String
    Dim intShp As Integer
    strWaterMark = InputBox("Please Enter the text you want to appear as Watermark", _
        "Enter Text Here:")
    With ActivePresentation.SlideMaster
        .Shapes.AddLabel msoTextOrientationHorizontal,
            .Width - 100, .Height - 100, 100, 100
        intShp = .Shapes.Count
        .Shapes.Item(intShp).TextFrame.TextRange = strWaterMark
        .Shapes.Item(intShp).Left = .Width - .Shapes.Item(intI).Width
        .Shapes.Item(intShp).Top = .Height - .Shapes.Item(intI).Height
    End With
End Sub
```

And the copy and paste method

```
Sub AddWaterMarkCopyPaste()
    Dim intI As Integer
    Dim intShp As Integer
    Dim strWaterMark As String
    strWaterMark = InputBox("Please Enter the text you want to appear as Watermark", _
        "Enter Text Here:")
    With ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(1)
        .Shapes.AddLabel msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
            .Master.Width - 100, .Master.Width - 100, 100, 100
        intShp = .Shapes.Count
        .Shapes.Item(intShp).TextFrame.TextRange = strWaterMark
        .Shapes.Item(intShp).Left = .Master.Width - .Shapes.Item(intShp).Width
        .Shapes.Item(intShp).Top = .Master.Height - .Shapes.Item(intShp).Height
        .Shapes.Item(intShp).Copy
    End With
    For intI = 2 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        With ActivePresentation.Slides(intI)
            .Shapes.Paste
            intShp = .Shapes.Count
            .Shapes.Item(intShp).Left = .Master.Width - .Shapes.Item(intShp).Width
            .Shapes.Item(intShp).Top = .Master.Height - .Shapes.Item(intShp).Height
        End With
    Next intI
End Sub
```