# How to Watermark image (with transparency) to all pptx slide using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have pptx slides with images on slides. I want to put watermark image with transparency on each slide. 
Want some VBA solution.

Comment: What kind of watermark do you want? How do you want to use it?

Comment: image overlay watermark.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54507190/4717755)