# How to delete VBA watermark on all slide?

Tags: vba, watermark

Please can any one help in deleting the watermark in all slide in attached code. I am trying but got error.

```
Sub WaterMarkwide()
Dim intI As Integer
Dim intShp As Integer
Dim strWaterMark As String
strWaterMark = InputBox("Please Enter the text you want to appear as Watermark", _
    "Enter Text Here:")
With ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(1)
    .Shapes.AddLabel msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        .Master.Width - 700, .Master.Width - 750, 20, 80
    intShp = .Shapes.Count
    .Shapes.Item(intShp).TextFrame.TextRange = strWaterMark
    .Shapes.Item(intShp).TextEffect.FontName = Arial
    .Shapes.Item(intShp).TextEffect.FontSize = 80
    .Shapes.Item(intShp).TextEffect.PresetTextEffect = msoTextEffect1
    .Shapes.Item(intShp).Rotation = 45
    .Shapes.Item(intShp).Copy
End With
For intI = 2 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(intI)
        .Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPastePNG
         intShp = .Shapes.Count
    End With
Next intI
```

End Sub

Comment: Your showing the code to *add* the watermark, not the attempt to delete it?!

Comment: Yes This is the code to show watermark.

Comment: But I want to make a button to delete Watermark from all slide. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The key here is understanding that there is no "watermark" feature in PowerPoint, as there is in MS Word. The code you've used correctly adds a shape to each slide that can be used as a watermark (from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54507190/4717755)).

The problem is: how can you detect which shape is the "watermark" shape after it's been added?

For this solution, I modified your original code to add a `Tag` to each shape that acts as a watermark. Then, when you run the code to delete, it's easy to look for the tag, identify the shape as a watermark, and delete it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Const WATERMARK_TAG As String = "WATERMARK"
Const WATERMARK_VALUE As String = "Watermark"

Sub WaterMarkwide()
    Dim strWaterMark As String
    strWaterMark = InputBox("Please Enter the text you want to appear as Watermark", _
                            "Enter Text Here:")
    
    Dim intShp As Integer
    With ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(1)
        .Shapes.AddLabel msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                         .Master.Width - 700, .Master.Width - 750, 20, 80
        intShp = .Shapes.Count
    End With
    
    With ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(1).Shapes.Item(intShp)
        .TextFrame.TextRange = strWaterMark
        .TextEffect.FontName = "Arial"
        .TextEffect.FontSize = 80
        .TextEffect.PresetTextEffect = msoTextEffect1
        .Rotation = 45
        .Tags.Add WATERMARK_TAG, WATERMARK_VALUE
        .Copy
    End With
    
    Dim intI As Integer
    For intI = 2 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        With ActivePresentation.Slides(intI)
            Dim shp As Shape
            .Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPastePNG
            Set shp = .Shapes.Item(.Shapes.Count)
            intShp = .Shapes.Count
            shp.Tags.Add WATERMARK_TAG, WATERMARK_VALUE
        End With
    Next intI
End Sub

Sub DeleteWatermark()
    Dim sld As Slide
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Dim shp As Shape
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Tags.Count > 0 Then
                Dim value As String
                value = shp.Tags.Item(WATERMARK_TAG)
                If value = WATERMARK_VALUE Then
                    shp.Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld
End Sub
```